# How to define a lambda function with a return type that can be used later with a generic

Tags: typescript, generics, lambda

I have a class using generics like such -

```
export class MyClass<T>
{
    constructor( private myCallback:()=>T)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

My callback is a lambda fucntion that returns a new object of type T. 
I'd like to be able to write code inside MyClass as such

```
let t:T = this.myCallback() ;
```

however i'm running into build errors. Seems the syntax is broken somewhere but i don't know where. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following compiles just fine [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/):

```
class MyClass<T> {
  constructor(private myCallback: () => T) {}

  thing(): T {
    const t: T = this.myCallback();
    return t;
  }
}

let s: string = new MyClass<string>(() => "hello").thing();
```